# AssertionError while trying to fit model python

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I keep on running into an AssertionError when trying to fit a model. I did some reading on when Python raises an AssertionError. The backlog is as follows

```
File "G:/test3/main.py", line 167, in <module>
model.fit([images, captions], next_words, batch_size=128, epochs=50)

File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 950, in fit
batch_size=batch_size)

File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 671, in _standardize_user_data
self._set_inputs(x)

File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 575, in _set_inputs
assert len(inputs) == 1

AssertionError
```

My code is as follows

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(Concatenate([image_model, language_model]))
model.add(LSTM(1000, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Nadam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([images, captions], next_words, batch_size=5, epochs=50)
model.summary()

model.save_weights("./models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
```

images has a shape of (18724,1000) and captions has a shape of (18724, 43)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you did not specify any inputs to your model, and Keras is trying to set them on calling `model.fit()`. The assertion is there because each model wrapped in a `Sequential` container should take only one input.

To implement what you want, you probably want to go for Keras' Functional API instead of the Sequential API. Something along these lines:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Concatenate, Input, Dense

# First model
first_input = Input((2, ))
first_dense = Dense(128)(first_input)

# Second model
second_input = Input((10, ))
second_dense = Dense(64)(second_input)

# Concatenate both
merged = Concatenate()([first_dense, second_dense])
output_layer = Dense(1)(merged)

model = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
```

Comment: I tried doing that, returns with an Attribute error  that Concatenate object has no attribute compile.

Comment: This would mean the answer from the related question is deprecated. I updated my answer, can you verify if this works?

Comment: As you may see in the code i provided, I have done the same work.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if this is possibly anymore with the Sequential API. I updated my answer with an example of how to do it with the functional API.

Comment: Running into a new error now, which asks for the inputs to the Concatenate layer to be symbolic tensors. Any clue on how i should do that?

`ValueError: Layer concatenate_7 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000000368098D9B0>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000000368098D320>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

Comment: And could you please explain the parameters of the Input layer for the first_input and second_input? Should i keep it as it is in the code you provided?

Comment: No, this is just some boilerplate to illustrate how you can concatenate the outputs of two models. You will have to adapt the code to fit your usecase.

Comment: Hey, so I tried doing what you suggested and it worked. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Nice to hear that!